# Splitting a string in a few substrings without string.split

Tags: c#, substring

First of all, here is my code:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string str = "test1,test2,test3";
        }
    }
}
```

So, I want to split test1 test2 and test3 using substrings and give it out in a console via `console.writeline()`. I want to use the "," for it. I'm not allowed to use `string.split`. Could you help me?

Comment: What is wrong with `.Split()`?

Comment: You can use Regulaer Expression

Comment: Easiest way is Split function and this is pre defined approach

Comment: Try `Regex.Split`. It's not `String.Split` :D

Comment: `string` is essentially an array of `char`. So you can very easily iterate through it, and accumulate the chars, until you reach a comma.

Comment: Best way to do that is with a pen and paper. Process the string by hand on a paper. Then you will have a valid pseudo code. You can start from there. Either you look for a comma and take the 1rst part of the string or you check if each char is a comma.

Comment: @Vischi - The way SO works is by you should show what you have tried. Then we can help correct it. Otherwise it is just as if doing your homework\assignments for you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [simple solution](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Y63HJ0) for you by using `.IndexOf()` and `.Substring()` methods.

```
string strInput = "test1,test2,test3,";
while (strInput.Length > 0)
{
    int commaIndex = strInput.IndexOf(',');
    if (commaIndex != -1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(strInput.Substring(0, commaIndex));
        strInput = strInput.Substring(commaIndex + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(strInput);
        strInput = "";
    }
}
```

Where,

> [`String.IndexOf Method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netframework-4.7.2) Reports the zero-based index of the first
>   occurrence of a specified Unicode character or string within this
>   instance. The method returns -1 if the character or string is not
>   found in this instance. And [`String.Substring Method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Substring_System_Int32_System_Int32_) will help you to Retrieves a substring from the given instance.

Answer (score 2):

This will work!

```
 class Program  
    {  
        static void Main(string[] args)  
        {  

            string str = "Test,Data";  
            ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();  
            string Temp = "";  
            for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)  
            {  

                if (str[i] != ',')  
                {  
                    Temp = Temp + str[i];  
                    continue;  
                }  


                arrayList.Add(Temp);  
                Temp = "";  
            }  
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the no 1 to " + arrayList.Count);  
            int option =Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());  
            if (option < arrayList.Count && option > 0)  
            {  
                Console.WriteLine(option+ " position is  = " +arrayList[option - 1]);  
            }  
            else  
            {  
                Console.WriteLine("Enter only 1 to " + arrayList.Count);  
            }  
            Console.ReadLine();  
        }  
    }
```

Comment: Why you are not allowed ? can please tell specifically

Comment: its "like" a homework. I'm a trainee in developement, and my trainer gave me that task. He wants me to figure it out. string.split is not allowed because it would make it too easy. :D

Comment: Great @Vischi : You want your homework questions to be solved on stackoverflow.
Cheers man.. ! But you will not learn any thing of coding, if you would not try to solve your homework yourself.

Answer (score 1):

**For a non-regex answer:**

```
string str = "test1,test2,test3";
string currentSubStr = string.Empty;
foreach (char c in str)
{
    if (c == ',')
    {
        Console.WriteLine(currentSubStr);
        currentSubStr = string.Empty;
    }
    else
    {
        currentSubStr = currentSubStr + c;
    }
}
```

This works for a very simply comma separated list, but if you're dealing with a csv file then you would be better off using a proper csv parser.